# $addToSet nested nested object using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

As part of a for-in loop in python using pymongo I want to add some nested documents/objects inside a `linktype` field which is to be within a `links` field:
neither the `links` field or `linktype` field exists before the first such entries are to be added.

What is the commands to do this ?

Here is an item before adding links:

```
item = {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5067c26b9d595266e25e825a"),
    "name": "a Name"
}
```

And after adding one link of type `typeA`:

```
toType = "typeA"
to_link = {"_id" : ObjectId("5067c26b9d595266e25e825b"), "property":"value"}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5067c26b9d595266e25e825a"),
    "name": "a Name",
    "links" : {
        "typeA":{
            {"_id" : ObjectId("5067c26b9d595266e25e825b"), "property":"value"}       
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried:

```
db.collection.update({"name":"a Name"},{{"links":{"$addToSet":{toType:to_link}}})
```

which doesnt work.
If I just use:

```
db.collection.update({"name":"a Name"},{ {"$addToSet":{toType:to_link}} )
```

that works but that is not what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$addToSet` is for adding to an array.  To add a new property to an existing embedded object you need to use the [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/set/) operator and [dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29) as:

```
db.collection.update({name: 'a name'}, {$set: {'links.' + toType: to_link}})
```

Comment: I just realised I actually wanted `typeA` to be an array of objects. so using your answer I have realised i was looking for: `from_collection.update({"ID":fromID},{"$addToSet":{'links.'+toType: to_link}})`. though you have answered my question as it stood.